# Custom shading pattern for tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking for a way to achieve a different node shading than with the 'usual' way

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[top color=red, bottom color=green] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this example, there is a gradient, i.e. the middle color is different from the actual top and bottom color. 
Is it possible to change it, i.e. to have a hard separation of the colors (top= red, bottom=green) without any different middle color or to change the properties of the gradient?

Comment: add `middle color` ?

Comment: @percusse but then it wouldn't be 50% red, 50% green anymore, right?

Comment: then it is not a shading but a `fill`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,
    append after command={
        \pgfextra
            \fill[green] (\tikzlastnode.south west) rectangle (\tikzlastnode.east);
            \fill[red] (\tikzlastnode.north west) rectangle (\tikzlastnode.east);
    \endpgfextra
    }] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update*

or even easier with a `path picture` option:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, fill=red,
        path picture={\fill[green] (path picture bounding box.west) rectangle (path picture bounding box.south east);}] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```